# Error of taking Screenshot using Java Robot Class

Tags: java, screenshot, netbeans

I tried to take screenshot  using java Robot class with NetBeans, as it is shown below

```
    try {
Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage capture  = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screen);

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(capture);
jLabel1.setIcon(icon);


}catch(Exception  ex){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
}
```

and I got this error

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f58931331d8, pid=3254, tid=0x00007f5890750700
>   JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b11) (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b11 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>   Problematic frame:
>   C  [libawt_xawt.so+0x421d8]  ReadRegionsInList+0x3b8
>   Core dump written. Default location: /home/sanaa/Desktop/server/RobotExample/core or core.3254

any idea what is causing the error ?

***Note***: I used the same code in windows-32bits /Netbeans and it works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you hit a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) in your Java Runtime:

I can't tell you exactly what you're problem is but I can tell you that somehow, the JRE tried to access, allocate, or deallocate memory that didn't belong to it as [explained in the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/crashes001.html).

Start off by making sure that you have the latest version of the JRE, and that it is the correct one for your OS (also make sure 32 v 64 bit is correct).

If you can reliably reproduce the issue and it's on the latest version of the JRE that is correctly installed, I suggest that you raise an official bug report with Oracle.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se] **;-)** Could you please [edit] your answer and clarify it a bit like where to download the latest JRE? Also please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1152097/revisions) to improve the readability of your answers in the future. **0:-)**